# Simple Jquery show hide problem

Tags: jquery

Quick one -

I have an image map and when rolling over a area i wish to show hide divs relevant to the area rolled over.

If i use the following code it works apart from that fact that when you remain hovered on the selected area it keeps the div hidden until you then mouse out - even though the show function is after the hide?

```
$(".part-sp").hover(
    function() {
        $(".map-logo").hide();
    }, function() {
        $(".map-sp").show();
    }    
);
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I've understood your question correctly, but it seems like you're confused about the `hover()` method.  The first argument should be the action to perform on mouse over, and the second argument should be the action to perform on mouse out.  So to show on mouse over and hide on mouse out, your function should look like this:

```
$(".part-sp").hover(
    function() {
        $(".map-sp").show();
    }, function() {
        $(".map-sp").hide();
    }    
);
```

Comment: Good lord - I think I need to have my morning coffe - i was looking at this the wrong way around! thanks.

Comment: @squeaker - We've all done it. Don't forget to make the answer as correct as well (assuming that it is).

Answer (score 0):

I think you try to show the wrong element when calling show().

Check out the result pane here http://jsfiddle.net/h9VK2/

Answer (score 0):

Even am a little confused about your question. Are you saying you dont want it to be hidden permanently when them mouse is over the Div ? Or it should fadeout and then fadein back ?

well your code as of now is correct and @Andy what you have specified is the other way which is again correct , but if you need is just a fadeOut FadeIn effect then use

```
$(".part-sp").hover(
    function() {
        $(".map-sp").fadeOut().fadeIn(); 
    },
   function() {
        $(".map-sp").show(); 
    } 
);
```

I dont know, but this may help. flip the fadeIn FadeOut if you want it the other way.